# Does Node.js have an equivalent to `open_basedir`?

Tags: php, node.js, security, express, open-basedir

I'm pretty familiar with security in Apache/Nginx + PHP setups.

In Apache I can set `DocumentRoot` and in PHP I can use `open_basedir` to restrict access parts of the file system that shouldn't be accessible to the web server and/or PHP.

However, now that I've created an application run by Node and Express, I'm finding it difficult to secure it. I've searched the web and SO but without finding anything but small scope security tips.

So, does Node/Express have an equivalent to `open_basedir` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express will not share any file without your consent. Also does not allow routes with double dots (`..`) in the received path.

Just use the `static` middleware and take care of not give access to folders with stuff that you don't want to share:

```
app.use('/images', express.static('/home/user/images');
app.use('/', express.static('/home/user/public'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this also cover if a hacker is successful in injecting a piece of code? In Apache/PHP `open_basedir` would prevent such an attack from having any effect. I sadly know little of security in regards to Node and JS on the server.

Comment: Express or node will not evaluate like code any of the route. At least that you explicit implement the logic to make it so, of course.